# How can I trigger Orleans Grain to re-activate?

Tags: .net, orleans

If I have to perform an operation on the persistence layer behind an Orleans set of Grains how to I ensure those grains affected can re-activate against the updated data?

My example is I have a grain at the Employee record level (EmployeeID as the Grain ID) and I need to perform a bulk operation against some of the records.  Obviously its important I ensure the grains re-load there state after this operation.

I have created an Orleans silo with grains to perform various operations including the employee change one.  I am using the GetGrain functionality as below

```cs
var employeeGrain = _clusterClient.GetGrain<IEmployeeGrain>(employeeId, "employee");
```

This grain will remain active while its used based on the standard Orleans lifecycle. My question is if I knowlingly perform an action that changes the underlying data how do I trigger the affected grains to re-activate?

From the official documentation
https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/1.5/Documentation/Advanced-Concepts/Activation-Garbage-Collection.html

It seems that you can force an individual grain to deactivate

```cs
this.DeactivateOnIdle()
```

But if I do a larger operation I'd want to avoid doing this per grain?  I guess ideally recycling all grains of a particular type.

Comment: Jon, welcome to SO. Could you add some detail on what you have tried already and what is not working?

Answer (score 5):

> This grain will remain active while its used based on the standard Orleans lifecycle. My question is if I knowlingly perform an action that changes the underlying data ...

I think you are not fully understanding how Orleans is working. You aren't allowed to change the underlaying data w/o going through the grain, that's the whole single point of it. If you do, you break the "single threaded execution" promise which Orleans grants you.

For me it seems you are still stuck to the old non-actor model way of thinking.

For Orleans (or actor pattern in general), the grain needs to be only modified through the actor itself. Only then this guarantee is given.

Also the way it is, actors also act as a kind of hot caching, where recently accessed actors state will remain in memory and not require any database. This works because the grain is only ever handled by a single thread in a single silo, which means that the state can't ever be changed by multiple-threads at the same time (and hence no synchronization or locking is required).

The "single threaded execution" guarantees that one actor will only ever be executed by a single thread at any given time. This is which gives Orleans is ability to scale infinitely, as there is no concurrency issues (However, you can still get deadlocks of grain A tries to access grain B, while grain B tries to access grain A and the method is not marked reentrant).

> ... how do I trigger the affected grains to re-activate?

Of course you can restart the silo cluster as part of an off-line migration (to a new data model), but I'd rather be careful about this as again, changing data outside the grain may break any consistency and guaranteed class invariant by doing so. In that case you shutdown the cluster, update/migrate your existing data, deploy the new version of your software and then start the cluster with the updated model.

Alternatively, if your grains don't persist any state (are stateless) you may run then as stateless grains with a specific live-time after they get deactivated and their state will get updated on their next activation. This works well in scenarios where Orleans is used as a hot-cache (i.e. for running an search operation and having the results cached for a bit to reduce database hits)